# Existence and uniqueness of formal adjoint operator on manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, adjoint-operators

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a (pseudo)-Riemannian manifold and $E$ a real vector bundle over $\mathcal{M}$, which we equip with a non-degenerate metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{E}\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E^{\ast}\otimes_{s} E^{\ast})$. This induces a bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\Gamma^{\infty}(E)}$ on the level of sections defined by

$$\langle s,t\rangle_{\Gamma^{\infty}(E)}:=\int_{\mathcal{M}}\langle s,t\rangle_{E}\,\mathrm{vol}_{g}$$

defined for all $s,t\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ with compactly overlapping support, where $\langle s,t\rangle_{E}\in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$ is understood as $\langle s,t\rangle_{E}(p):=\langle s(p),t(p)\rangle_{E_{p}}$. In the theory of PDEs on manifolds, one often sees the following definition.

Consider a linear operator $D:\Gamma^{\infty}(E)\to\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$. Then, it is stated that there exists a unique linear operator $D^{\ast}:\Gamma^{\infty}(E)\to\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$, the "formal adjoint of $D$", such that

$$\langle Ds,t\rangle_{\Gamma^{\infty}(E)}=\langle s,D^{\ast}t\rangle_{\Gamma^{\infty}(E)}$$

for all $s,t\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ with $\mathrm{supp}(s)\cap\mathrm{supp}(t)$ compact. Now, my question is:

> **Question:** Why does this operator exists and why is it unique?

In general, $(\Gamma^{\infty}(E),\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\Gamma^{\infty}(E)})$ is not a Hilbert space, so we cannot use the standard 'Riesz representation theorem'-argument usually used in functional analysis for the proper definition of adjoint operators. Furthermore, I am not even sure that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\Gamma^{\infty}(E)}$ is non-degenerate, even if $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{E}$ is non-degenerate, so also uniquness is not clear to me.

Every comment and idea is welcome.

Comment: I don't think it is true for *all* linear operators, but it should hold for smooth differential operators and can be proven in local charts (the adjoint will again be a differential operators, hence local). Also, at least on Riemannian manifolds (I'm not very familiar with the pseudo-Riemannian side), the volume measure has full support so that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)}$ is non-degenerate.

Comment: Yes indeed, in the ressources I had in mind stating this fact, it is assumed that $D$ is a linear differential operator. I was not reading carefully enough^^ How does one proof existence? With some integration by parts/Stokes theorem type of argument I guess?

Comment: Yes, I would use integration by parts in a local chart and then use locality of the involved operators to show that you can patch the charts together. But I still hope some expert on this topic comes along with a suitable reference (I'm sure it's somewhere in the literature).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof for a compact Riemannian manifold (I'm not very familiar with pseudo-Riemannian manifolds).
Let $r$ be the rank of $E$, and let $m$ be the order of $D$.

Uniqueness follows by the standard argument from linear algebra: if we have operators $P, Q \colon \Gamma^\infty(E) \to \Gamma^\infty(E)$ such that $\langle Ds, t \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)} = \langle s, Pt \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)} = \langle s, Qt \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)}$ for all $s, t$, then $0 = \langle s, (P-Q)t \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)}$ for all $s, t$, so taking $s = (P-Q)t$ gives $P = Q$.

For existence, choose a finite cover of $M$ by coordinate charts $x_\ell \colon U_\ell \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ for $\ell = 1, \ldots, N$ over each of which is defined a trivialisation $E \rvert_{U_\ell} \to U_\ell \times \mathbb{R}^r$ whose induced local frame is orthonormal.
Further, choose a partition of unity $\{\chi_\ell\}_{\ell=1}^N$ subordinate to the cover $\{U_\ell\}_{\ell=1}^N$.
If we write $D = \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \leq m} A_\ell^\alpha \partial^{\lvert \alpha \rvert}/\partial x^\alpha$ on $U_\ell$ for each $\ell$, then
\begin{align}
    \langle Ds, t \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)}
    &= \sum_{\ell=1}^N \langle Ds, \chi_\ell t \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)} \\
    &= \sum_{\ell=1}^N \int_{U_\ell} \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \leq m} \biggl( A^\alpha_\ell \frac{\partial^{\lvert \alpha \rvert} s}{\partial x^\alpha}\biggr)^{\!\intercal} \chi_\ell t \operatorname{vol}_{g_\ell} \\
    &= \sum_{\ell=1}^N \int_{U_\ell} s^\intercal \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g_\ell}} \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \leq m} (-1)^{\lvert \alpha \rvert} \frac{\partial^{\lvert \alpha \rvert}}{\partial x^\alpha} \Bigl( \sqrt{\det g_\ell} (A^\alpha_\ell)^\intercal \chi_\ell t \Bigr) \operatorname{vol}_{g_\ell} \\
    &= \sum_{\ell=1}^N \int_{U_\ell} s^\intercal D_\ell^* t \operatorname{vol}_{g_\ell}
\end{align}
where the third line follows by integration by parts (there are no boundary terms because $x_\ell(U_\ell) = \mathbb{R}^n$), and in the fourth line we have defined
\begin{equation}
    D_\ell^* t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g_\ell}} \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \leq m} (-1)^{\lvert \alpha \rvert} \frac{\partial^{\lvert \alpha \rvert}}{\partial x^\alpha} \Bigl( \sqrt{\det g_\ell} (A^\alpha_\ell)^\intercal \chi_\ell t \Bigr).
\end{equation}
Since the right-hand side of the above is supported $U_\ell$, this formula actually defines a global operator $D_\ell^* \colon \Gamma^\infty(E) \to \Gamma^\infty(E)$; moreover, it is a partial differential operator of order $m$.
Hence $D^* = \sum_{\ell=1}^N D_\ell^* \colon \Gamma^\infty(E) \to \Gamma^\infty(E)$ is a partial differential operator of order $m$, and we have
\begin{equation}
    \langle Ds, t \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)} 
    = \sum_{\ell=1}^N \int_{U_\ell} u^\intercal (D_\ell^* v) \operatorname{vol}_{g_\ell}
    = \sum_{\ell=1}^N \langle s, D_\ell^* t \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)}
    = \langle s, D^* t \rangle_{\Gamma^\infty(E)},
\end{equation}
which is the desired property.